# Given a string that's a weekday name, how to figure out weekday as decimal (and the next date it occurs)?

Tags: python, datetime, optimization

Given a string, `reqDayOf`, that's a weekday name, how do you figure out weekday as decimal (and then return the next instance of it based on a `datetime` object)?

Getting the `datetime` object's year and iso Week of Year and then using `strptime` with the year + week of year + the weekday name works, but it feels like a hack.

```
import datetime

def getDateFromDayOf(dateTimeObj,reqDayOf):
  #reqDayOf is one of ['monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday','sunday']
  #return the next instance of reqDayOf
  #after dateTimeObj
  #as a datetime object 
  #Get the WeekOfYear from dateTimeObj and then
  #get the date based on Year + WeekOfYear + reqDayOf 
  (dtoYear,dtoIsoWeek,x)=dateTimeObj.isocalendar()
  checkDate= '{}-{}-{}'.format( dtoYear,dtoIsoWeek,reqDayOf)
  dateOfDay=datetime.datetime.strptime(checkDate,"%Y-%U-%A")
  #return dateOfDay if it's greater than the original date
  if dateOfDay > dateTimeObj:
    return dateOfDay
  else:
    #this is needed on Sundays
    #add a week
    return dateOfDay + datetime.timedelta(days=7)  


>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%a %Y %b %d')
'Fri 2013 Apr 05'
>>> getDateFromDayOf(datetime.datetime.now(),'Monday').strftime('%a %Y %b %d')
'Mon 2013 Apr 08'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The day of the week (as an integer) is returned by the [weekday method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday):

```
import datetime as DT
dow = dict(zip('monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday'.split(),
           range(7)))

def getDateFromDayOf(dateTimeObj, reqDayOf):
    weekday = dateTimeObj.weekday()        
    return dateTimeObj + DT.timedelta(days=(dow[reqDayOf.lower()]-weekday-1)%7+1)
```

---

```
In [90]: getDateFromDayOf(DT.datetime.now(), 'Monday').date()
Out[90]: datetime.date(2013, 4, 8)

In [91]: getDateFromDayOf(DT.datetime.now(), 'Tuesday').date()
Out[91]: datetime.date(2013, 4, 9)

In [92]: getDateFromDayOf(DT.datetime.now(), 'Friday').date()
Out[92]: datetime.date(2013, 4, 12)
```

---

Or, using [dateutil](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil),

```
import datetime as DT
import dateutil
import dateutil.relativedelta as rdelta
import dateutil.rrule as rrule

dow = dict(zip('monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday'.split(),
               (getattr(rdelta, d) for d in 'MO TU WE TH FR SA SU'.split())))
def getDateFromDayOf(dateTimeObj, reqDayOf):
    rr = rrule.rrule(
        rrule.DAILY,                       # step by days
        byweekday = dow[reqDayOf.lower()], # return only this day of the week
        dtstart = dateTimeObj)             # start on this day 
    res = rr.after(dateTimeObj, inc=False) # inc=False means don't include the dtstart day
    return res
```

Using dateutil you can express the idea in a high-level manner, without having to worry about off-by-one errors in grubby details like

```
DT.timedelta(days=(dow[reqDayOf.lower()]-weekday-1)%7+1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to the weekday method in [@unutbu's anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15835012/355230), but implemented in a way that doesn't require the day names (or their abbreviations) to be hardcoded into it. It uses the `datetime.date`'s `toordinal()` method to convert the date to a single number, then figures out how many days to add to it to get the desired weekday, and lastly converts the new number back into a date using the `date.fromordinal()` method.

It creates and uses a dictionary named `DAYNUMS` to convert the `reqDayOf` weekday name into a number from 1 to 7, and the `date.isoweekday()` method is used to do likewise for the `dateTimeObj` argument which was passed to it. The `DAYNUMS` dictionary is created without using hardcoded day names, so it will also work in non-English locales and languages given an appropriate `reqDayOf` argument, such as `'lundi'` instead of `'Monday'` for French locales.

```
import datetime

# Create dictionary based on fact that 2013-April-01 was a Monday.
DAYNUMS = {datetime.date(2013, 4, i).strftime('%A').lower(): i
               for i in range(1, 8)}

def getDateFromDayOf(dateTimeObj, reqDayOf):
    daysDiff = (DAYNUMS[reqDayOf.lower()] - dateTimeObj.isoweekday() - 1) % 7 + 1
    return datetime.date.fromordinal(dateTimeObj.toordinal() + daysDiff)

a_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2013-04-05', '%Y-%m-%d')
print(a_date.strftime('%a %Y %b %d'))                              # -> Fri 2013 Apr 05
print(getDateFromDayOf(a_date, 'Monday').strftime('%a %Y %b %d'))  # -> Mon 2013 Apr 08
```